# redis rsmq worker unable to fetch message from redis queue

Tags: node.js, docker, redis

I am attempting to write rsmq worker integration with redis + node + docker.

I have created three separate containers

1. producer
2. redis
3. consumer

All three containers are working on the same machine (`localhost`). When I am going to send the message to redis queue from producer container, It works successfully but the consumer is not able to pull the message from the same queue automatically.

However, I have gone through all three containers and verified network configuration. It's make ping.I have used rsmq-worker as redis consumer.

To my surprise, it works in below two scenarios

1. I moved my consumer to the same container as REDIS container and it pulls message. However, as I mentioned, when the consumer is in a separate container than REDIS it does not work.
2. Also when I have three separate containers and I use rsmq-cli and try rsmq receive -h redis-Ip -q simple-test from consumer container and it fetches the message

I believe there is some issue in rsmq-worker with the container. Has anyone faced this before? Any suggestions?

I am attaching code also for reference.

> Consumer.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var RedisSMQ = require("rsmq");
var rsmq = new RedisSMQ({ host: "18.232.206.185", port: 6379, ns: "rsmq" });
var RSMQWorker = require("rsmq-worker");
var rsmqTestWorker = new RSMQWorker("simple-test", { timeout: '0' });
var router = express.Router();

var allowCrossDomain = function (req, res, next) {

    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type,userId,x-onehop-token,businessId,corporateId');
    if (req.method == 'OPTIONS') {
        res.status(200).end();
    } else {
        console.log("------------------Req URL-----------------");
        console.log("Req.URL :: ", req.path);
        console.log("------------------Req method-----------------");
        console.log("Req.params :: ", req.method);
        console.log("--------------------------------------------");
        next();
    }
    // next();
};
app.use(allowCrossDomain);
app.use(bodyParser.json({
    limit: '50mb'
}));
//app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    limit: '50mb',
    extended: true,
    parameterLimit: 100000000
}));

rsmqTestWorker.on("message", function(msg, next, id) {
    // process your message
    console.log("rsmqTestWorker process Message id : " + id);
    console.log(msg);
    next();

});

// optional error listeners
rsmqTestWorker.on('error', function(err, msg) {
    console.log("rsmqTestWorker ERROR", err, msg.id);
});
rsmqTestWorker.on('exceeded', function(msg) {
    console.log("rsmqTestWorker EXCEEDED", msg.id);
});
rsmqTestWorker.on('timeout', function(msg) {
    console.log("rsmqTestWorker TIMEOUT", msg.id, msg.rc);
});

var server = app.listen(5000, function () {
    console.log('Server listening on port 5000');
    rsmqTestWorker.start();
});
```

> Producer.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var RedisSMQ = require('rsmq');
var rsmq = new RedisSMQ({
    "host": '18.232.206.185',
    "port": 6379,
    ns: 'rsmq'
});
var allowCrossDomain = function (req, res, next) {

    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type,userId,x-onehop-token,businessId,corporateId');
    if (req.method == 'OPTIONS') {
        res.status(200).end();
    } else {
        console.log("------------------Req URL-----------------");
        console.log("Req.URL :: ", req.path);
        console.log("------------------Req method-----------------");
        console.log("Req.params :: ", req.method);
        console.log("--------------------------------------------");
        next();
    }
    // next();
};
app.use(allowCrossDomain);
app.use(bodyParser.json({
    limit: '50mb'
}));
//app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    limit: '50mb',
    extended: true,
    parameterLimit: 100000000
}));

app.get("/send-sms", (req, res) => {
    rsmq.sendMessage({ qname: "simple-test", message: "Hello World" }, function (err, resp) {
        if (resp) {
            console.log("Message sent. ID:", resp);
            res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify({ status: "success" ,resp:resp }));
        }
    });
});

var server = app.listen(4000, function () {
    console.log('Server listening on port 4000');

    rsmq.createQueue({
        qname: "simple-test",
        maxsize: -1
    }, function (error, resp) {
        if (resp === 1) {
            console.log("simple-test queue created");
        } else {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Why hardcore an IP address for redis in there? Should just be able to access it by the hostname "redis". Make sure you're running all containers on a common user created network.

Comment: Yes, I have tried with hardcore IP address. It makes ping & all the three containers are created in the same instance (same network). - @BMitch

Answer (score 1):

```
new RSMQWorker("simple-test", { timeout: '0' });
```

**It needs to** init with a redis connection or a rsmq instance, the default redis host is 127.0.0.1 with port 6379

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a dev problem instead of Docker problem. Have you try out your 2 microservices outside a container ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried outside a container. It's working.

Comment: @Mech45 he wants to run both things on the separate container and communicate with each other as per the question.

Comment: @Dipakchavda yes I understood, but when he runs the redis CLI command everything went fine, so its probably a code base error. The CLI use the same way to communicate than the redis api !

Comment: @Mech45 hmm yes